flask - Python script returning KeyError when testing Login success screen
I'm making a Python script, opening a link that asks for a username and password and a login button which shows you your details, showing that the process have been completed. My problem is that, though the login page works, it gives a KeyError when I press the login button.
Here's my code:
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def RedirectToLogin():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        
        return '''
            <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    .details-container {
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                        height: 100vh;
                        font-size: 24px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .form-container {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        width: 200px;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                    }
                    .form-input {
                        margin-bottom: 10px;
                    }
                    .smooth-button {
                        border-radius: 12px;
                        padding: 10px 20px;
                        background-color: black;
                        color: white;
                        border: none;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        margin-top: 20px;
                    }
                    .smooth-button:hover {
                        background-color: #45a049;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="details-container">
                    <div>
                        <p>Username: {0}</p>
                        <p>Password: {1}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        '''.format(username, password)
    
    return '''
        <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .form-container {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    width: 200px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                
                .form-input {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                }
                
                .smooth-button {
                    border-radius: 12px;
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                    border: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                }
                
                .smooth-button:hover {
                    background-color: #45a049;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="/login" class="form-container">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-input"><br>
                
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-input"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="smooth-button">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

What I expected:

Username: [User input for username]
Password: [User input for password]
[Login] <---- button
Username: [Inputted username]
Password: [Inputted password]
What I got

Username: [User input for username]
Password: [User input for password]
[Login] <---- button
KeyError
KeyError: '\n                        display'
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in call
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py",
line 1476, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py",
line 1473, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py",
line 882, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py",
line 880, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py",
line 865, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\ABC\Desktop\VsCode Projects\Python Projects\Login-Page-with-Flask.py",
line 59, in login
'''.format(username, password)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Open an interactive python shell in this frame
KeyError: '\n display'
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline.
From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.
You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:
dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

All help will be greatly appreciated.

You have many unescaped braces in your HTML+CSS code. Python considers all braces to be placeholders and is trying to substitute them all. and, you have only supplied two values. One solution is escaping all the braces. But the best solution is using templates nad not putting bare html code in python code.
